# Local Password Storage in .NET

Tags: .net, security, rest

I am writing a WPF application that uses REST to communicate with a remote web service.  The application requires that a user enters their username and password since some features of the REST API require authentication.  I am wondering how to store the password securely in my WPF application.  On the service side I am storing it by salting it with a random salt and then using SHA256 to hash this.  Should I create a REST command that returns the secured password (i.e hashed and salted password) and provide that to the server when using REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store it locally at all. Pass it via HTTPS to the server and have the server return an authentication token that can be used on subsequent calls instead of the login. The token can be just an arbitrary random number with no connection to a particular user except via a mapping on the server. You are using HTTPS for your REST calls, right? You'll need login and logout functions, login to generate the authentication token and logout to invalidate it, plus you can put an expiration date on the token to limit how long it is valid for.

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay to prompt the user for username and password every time he/she starts the WPF application, then keep the credentials in memory. You can use [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to keep the password out of memory dumps.

If you don't want to prompt the user for credentials every time he/she starts the application, take a look at using [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/). Your application will have the user authenticate against an authorization server. This server returns both an access token and a refresh token. You can use the access token to talk to the REST API and can use the refresh token to get a new access token when it expires.

It you want to store the refresh token securely on the user's machine, look at Windows Data Protection ([DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx)) to encrypt the token before storing it.